# Price gets multiplied by 100 when saving product in Spree (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

I installed the online shopping framework Spree on top of Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.3. I also use the Spree_i18n gem to localize the shop. Now, whenever I save a product, the price is multiplied by 100.

For example, in the admin area, I type the price 3.20. That results in the value 320. If I save again, it changes to 32000 and so on.

Here is my localized de_numbers.yml for reference:

```
---
de:
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        format: "%u%n"
        unit: "€"
        precision: 2
        separator: '.'
        delimiter: ','
```

I can not think of anything unusual in my setup so I wonder why this is not a common problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, do you have the seeded db or starting from scratch with products?

Comment: Tried to replicate this, it possibly has to do with your currency file OR that you're using , instead of .

Comment: I neither has to do with my currency file nor my usage of , or . - see my comment to first answer.

Comment: I found the solution, I believe, which requires a modification to the "spree-core" and is now in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**

**spree-core:** the Product form is not handling displaying product.price and product.cost_price with regards to I18n / localization. To fix this to work for you, you'll need to modify the core. I'm going to post to the Spree Core team about this, but in the interim, I've tested this fix and it should work.

In **/gems/spree_core-1.0.0/app/views/spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb**, you will need to modify these lines:

```
<%= f.text_field :price, :value => number_with_precision(@product.price, :precision => 2) %>
```

to be this:

```
<%= f.text_field :price, :value => number_with_precision(@product.price, :precision => I18n.t('number.currency.format.precision'), :separator => I18n.t('number.currency.format.separator'), :delimiter => I18n.t('number.currency.format.delimiter')) %>
```

and this:

```
<%= f.text_field :cost_price, :value => number_with_precision(@product.cost_price, :precision => 2) %>
```

to be this:

```
<%= f.text_field :cost_price, :value => number_with_precision(@product.cost_price, :precision => I18n.t('number.currency.format.precision'), :separator => I18n.t('number.currency.format.separator'), :delimiter => I18n.t('number.currency.format.delimiter')) %>
```

Essentially, we're making it handle I18n potential values.

**ORIGINAL:**

I've duplicated your file exactly, and tried a few tests to recreate this (create a new product, new product variant, change the product price, cost price, etc.). To re-create this, you need to create a de_numbers.yml, and flip your localization to be 'de' in the Spree initializer with "config.default_locale = 'de'"

Here are some suggested fixes:

1. make sure you run bundle install
2. in your Gemfile, make sure you're using the latest version of i18n (

> gem 'spree_i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git')

1. fix your whitespace to be 2 spaces, instead of tabs (this is **potentially a white-space issue where it can't read your i18n values**)
2. Go into the rails console, and log out the values (i.e.

> I18n.t('number.currency.format.unit')

1. Try getting this to work in "en" locale first and then "de".
2. Put your values into the "de.yml" or "en.yml" first and see if they work before putting into a "de_currency.yml" file.

Comment: I checked everything you suggested and it was working though I think you meant de_numbers.yml file? I removed the spree_i18n gem from my Gemfile and did a 'bundle install'. Input of price worked correct then. I reinstalled the spree_i18n gem and the problem occured again (even without a de_numbers.yml file). I noticed that without the spree_i18n gem, the floating point in the input field remains. But with the gem, it is removed thus 3.20 is interpreted as 320 which after the next save is interpreted ans 32000.

Comment: Update: the problem only occurs when I switch to the 'de' locale. I guess I could manually set the locale for the admin area to 'en' but this would only be a workaround and not solve the issue.

Comment: Wow, by changing my translation to use "de", I was able to replicate this. It has to do with the forms rendering the values WITHOUT a '.'. I'm going to find this further, but I'm pretty sure if you re-input the cost properly (i.e. 1.99 => 199, just change back to 1.99) and submit, you'll be fine. I'm not sure why the form for 'de' is stripping out the '.' character...

Comment: I've isolated this down to gems/spree_core-1.0.0/app/views/spree/admin/products/_form.html.erb. The lines there involve displaying the values in the form "<%= f.text_field :price, :value => number_with_precision(@product.price, :precision => 2) %>". However, I'm wondering if that needs to have a :locale => something property. That or we need to replace that with "number_to_currency product.price rescue ''". Still researching. This might be an issue with the Spree core and something you should tell the team.

Comment: If you just output "@product.price", it's fine. The issue is that "number_with_precision" is not playing nice with locales. More has to be done to integrate the properties of the method based on the locale. I'll research later, don't have time now, but it involves pulling out the 'locale' settings and using them here (http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_precision)

Comment: I'm the Community Manager for Spree and I validate that this is a bug that we would take quite serious and we will probably spend some time looking into a proper fix for it this week if somebody else doesn't beat us to it. Thanks for the informative answer!

Comment: Thank you for so much help! I am happy to see that the Spree project ist so well supported.

Comment: Cool, we helped with Spree! Thanks Ryan!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've transposed the meanings of your separator and delimiter characters. The setup looks correct, so my thinking is that the price needs to be entered as

```
3,20
```

Rather than

```
3.20
```

[This discussion of currency formatting](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/numbers), although not specific to Ruby development, may provide additional insight.

Comment: The input of 3,20 is not accepted and does not change the price value - without an error message. I will look into that article about currency formatting

Comment: @Mark - when you say the input is not accepted... is there separate validation code that might be rejecting the input, or is the same function that converts the string to a numeric value having the issue?